# OnPostExecute() function is not executing in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello i'm developing an application that performs database queries on a remote server. so far i've successfully interacted with the PHP script on the server side and my code is sending string values without a problem, but i'm not sure how to check if i'm recieving back the values i'm sending back through my PHP script, as my OnPostExecute function is not responding.
Please Help.

Here's the code that's facing problem :

```
public void submit_data(View V){
    try{
        new DoSocketProgramming().execute("10.0.2.2");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "created till here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class DoSocketProgramming extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String sendsentence=" this message is sent\n";
    String recvsentence=null;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is preExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{            

            Socket con=new Socket(addr,1678);
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeUTF(sendsentence);
            recvsentence=dis.readUTF();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return recvsentence;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is post execute"+ recvsentence, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is, actually. The problem is that you're using `getApplicationContext()` as the `Context` and this is almost always wrong, you shouldn't use this unless you know exactly what you're doing.

When creating an `AsyncTask`, the constructor receives the `Context` of the `Activity` that invoked it, you should store this `Context` in your `AsyncTask` class and use it in your `onPostExecute()` method.

This would be an example:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
   Context context;

   private MyAsyncTask(Context context) { this.context = context; }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(...) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);

     Toast.makeText(context, "this is post execute"+ recvsentence, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting a `Log.d()` line prior to the `try` statement. Does it show up in the logcat?

Comment: Just put something like: `Log.d("MyApp", "I've reached onPostExecute()");`, when run, it should show up a line like that in your LogCat.

Comment: Try replacing your definition: `public class DoSocketProgramming extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>` with this: `public class DoSocketProgramming extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

Comment: still nothing !..we can have Input and Ouput Stream together in there !!!.. right ??

Comment: i tried to put Log.d in doinbackground() and its working...
that means only onPostExecute() is not...

Comment: It makes no sense, your code is ok. I just copied and pasted it into my project and it works as it should, the `Log.d()` in `onPostExecute()` is shown. You must be doing something wrong... are you sure you exit `doInBackground()` at any time??

Comment: No problem. Anytime you solve an issue you've asked, it's recommended (not mandatory) to accept the question that helped you most. You can do this checking the 'tick' under the points of the answer that you want to accept, this will make other users know that this answer was helpful.